# How to handle corrupted kafka topic partition data

Tags: apache-kafka

## issue

There was a time when a multiple disk failed due to a kernel issue while operating the kafka cluster. A cluster level down occurred.
There were multiple topics where the leader could not be maintained, and it took a long time to restore the topics data.
The same goes for internal topics.(eg. __consumer_offsets)
Afterwards, consumers could not connect to the broker.

## progress

Data reading process was performed when the isolation.level property was changed from read_committed to read_uncommitted.
 However, there is an issue of loading duplicate data, so I want to load only the committed data.

I do several tests to clarify the cause of the problem.
When i added new consumer, there was an issue with a specific partition could not be read.
[image]

**I think there is a conflict with the data of a specific partition of the topic.** Is there a good way to solve the problem without the restart broker or deleting the topic?

## Tried

1. Change the leader partition to other replica -> doesn't work
2. I debugged the consumer, then i found the reason. Those corrupted partitions couldn't join to the SubsriptionState.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current assignment for partition
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.assignedState(SubscriptionState.java:354)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.seekUnvalidated(SubscriptionState.java:371)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.seek(KafkaConsumer.java:1608)
at consumer.Consumer.main(Consumer.java:31)
```

Comment: If the replicas are healthy, you could force partition leader election to other replicas, then delete the corrupted replicas and let it replicate from the healthy instances

Comment: Thanks always, @OneCricketeer. I'll try

Comment: It doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you update the question with what you tried?